# Casting pointer to record type to non void pointer and back

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Sometimes, e.g. when interfacing C++ and C code, it can make sense to cast a pointer to a C++ object to `void *` and back. The following should be well defined for any C++ class `A`:

```
// (1)

A *a = new A(...);
void *a_void = static_cast<void *>(a);
a = static_cast<A *>(a_void);
```

But what if instead of casting `a` to `void *` I cast it to some other type, in particular a declared but not defined record type?

```
// (2)

struct foo;

A *a = new A(...);
foo *a_foo = reinterpret_cast<foo *>(a);
a = reinterpret_cast<A *>(a_foo);
```

And if that is well-defined, what about doing it in a "roundabout" way like so:

```
// (3)

struct foo;
struct bar;

A *a = new A(...);
foo *a_foo = reinterpret_cast<foo *>(a);
bar *a_bar = reinterpret_cast<bar *>(a_foo);
a = reinterpret_cast<A *>(a_bar);
```

My intuition is that (1) and (2) are well-defined but (3) is not because technically it's missing a `reinterpret_cast` from `a_bar *` to `a_foo *`. Is that correct?

Comment: [This paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) of the Standard seems to be relevant. I don't see any problem here up to that alignment part mentioned in the _Note 7_ there. I am not an expert but it sounds as that a pointer to `T2` may not be able to represent a pointer to `T1` if `T2` has stricter alignment requirements than `T1`.

Comment: Related question: [Can pointers to different types have different binary representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66102053/580083). This question basically cannot be answered since the correct answer would depend on the alignment information about the involved types, which you do not provide.

Comment: @DanielLangr: So are you saying my code is technically not well defined? I'm talking about the case where the structs are literally only declared but never defined. I don't know what the alignment requirements for pointers to such structs are though.

Comment: I am not sure about well-definition. According to [this sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.static.cast-13.sentence-2), the resulting pointer value might be _unspecified_ if the alignment requirements are not met. It's your responsibility not to make pointer conversions in such a case.